# Named query not known

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a mapping in NHibernate like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping namespace="News.BusinessEntity" assembly="News.BusinessEntity" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

    <class name="News" table="News">
       <property name="NewsId" type="Int64" column="NewsId"   />
       <property name="NewsTitle" type="String" column="NewsTitle"  />
    </class>

    <sql-query name="Sp_News">
           <return class="News" />
           exec Sp_News
    </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I call `session.GetNamedQuery("Sp_News")` I get the following error:

```
Named query not known: Sp_News.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the error was solved just by setting the Build Action property of .hbm.xml file to Embeded Resource

Answer (score 1):

The same error is thrown if the mapping file doesn't end with .hbm.xml.
I have accidentally renamed a mapping file and dropped the .hbm. from the name, putting it back solved this issue for me.